# Laravel Blade Echo

Tags: laravel-5, laravel-blade

Im trying to understand laravel.
In my test, I've created a controller like this :

```
    public function getDirectorySize( $path = null)
{ 
$path="/folder/"; 
$pathlog="/laravel.log"; 
$pathbackup="/folder/"; 
$ar=getDirectorySize($path); 

$totalsize = 0; 
$totalcount = 0; 
$dircount = 0; 
if ($handle = opendir ($path)) 
{ 
while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle))) 
{ 
  $nextpath = $path . '/' . $file; 
  if ($file != '.' && $file != '..' && !is_link ($nextpath)) 
  { 
    if (is_dir ($nextpath)) 
    { 
      $dircount++; 
      $result = getDirectorySize($nextpath); 
      $totalsize += $result['size']; 
      $totalcount += $result['count']; 
      $dircount += $result['dircount']; 
    } 
    elseif (is_file ($nextpath)) 
    { 
      $totalsize += filesize ($nextpath); 
      $totalcount++; 
    } 
  } 
} 
} 
closedir ($handle); 
$total['size'] = $totalsize; 
$total['count'] = $totalcount; 
$total['dircount'] = $dircount; 
return $total; 

}
```

in my blade i want to display data like this :

```
        Details for the path : {{ $path }} 
        Details for the log : {{ $pathlog }}
        Details for the backup : {{ $pathbackup }} 
        Total size : {{ sizeFormat($ar['size']) }}
        No. of files : {{ $ar['count'] }} 
        <? echo "No. of directories : ".$ar['dircount']."<br>"; ?>
```

But i got this error :

```
Undefined variable: path
```

I want to display any information from this function

Comment: Shouldn't you send those variables to the view?

Comment: i want to display $path to my blade view :(
any solution ?

Comment: ```return view('template, ['path' => $path]);```

Comment: i've add this to my controller :   $this->data = array('path'  => $path); but still not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try something like this?

```
public function yourControllerFunction() {
    $path="/folder/"; 
    $pathlog="/laravel.log"; 
    ...
    // Add variables you want to pass to the view
    $data = array(
        'path' => $path,
        'pathlog' => $pathlog,
    )
    return view('view_file', $data);
}
```

Then in the view you should be able to access $path and $pathlog.

Comment: i've add return view like this :  return view('builder.config.log',$this->data); but still with same problem.

Comment: The $data variable in my example is declared inside the controller function and hence there is no need for $this. Have you tried without $this?